# How to show different images using owl carousel on different resolutions ? WordPress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, image, responsive-design

Is it possible to use different images and to show those images based on screen resolution ? For example if I am 5 images like image1, image2, image3, image4 and image5. Then I want to show image1, image2 and image3 on desktop while when it comes to mobile devices I want to show only image4 and image4 nothing else.
Can we go in this way or any other way ? Any one to guide me hope its clear by now what I actually want to perform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can used this condition to set image as you like

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile

```
<?php
if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
    /* Display and echo mobile specific stuff here */
    }

?>
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, but the issue is that I am using this from owl carousel wordpress plugin

Comment: so, in that it is impossible to put any such tag that can work ? any other help or any thing in your mind further plz ?